# TypeError: o.nodeName is undefined

Tags: jquery

I'm getting this error in my code when i run. please any one can help me to fix it.
when i change the select box my ajax should run after 3 sec. That why i gave settimeout in code.

Here is my html code also.

```
<div id="edit-field-domain-tid-wrapper" class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-filter-field_domain_tid">
<label for="edit-field-domain-tid">
    Domain
</label>
<div class="views-widget">
    <div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-field-domain-tid">
        <select id="edit-field-domain-tid" name="field_domain_tid" class="form-select">
            <option value="All">
                - Any -
            </option>
            <option value="263">
                cptportal.hitbullseye.com
            </option>
            <option value="126">
                gdpi.hitbullseye.com
            </option>
            <option value="175">
                grad.hitbullseye.com
            </option>
            <option value="166" selected="selected">
                hitbullseye.com
            </option>
            <option value="244">
                law.hitbullseye.com
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   jQuery( "#edit-field-domain-tid" ).bind('change',function(event) {
      setTimeout( 
        function() 
        {
    event.preventDefault();

      jQuery.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:Drupal.settings.basePath + 'admin/sidebar-bullseye/sectionajax',
            dataType: 'html',
            data:{nid:jQuery(this).val()}
        }).done(function(data, textStatus, jQxhr){
            var ndata = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    if(ndata.message=="Success")
                    {

          var arr = ndata.res.split(',');
          jQuery(".select-wrapper select.form-select option").each(function(){
                    var opval=jQuery(this).attr('value');
                    if(opval!="_none")
                    {
                        jQuery(this).hide();
                    }
                   });
for(var k=0;k<arr.length;k++)
                   {
                      jQuery(".select-wrapper select.form-select option[value=" + arr[k] + "]").show();
                   }

                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
        });
        }, 3000);
});
```

});

Comment: could you provide the complete code!

Comment: this is the complete code

Comment: I am asking for html code.

Comment: Are you getting "drupal is not defined error" at console.